# Regex Expression

Tags: regex

Please find expression for example string :

```
john/niel
Stephanie/Arnold
```

I wrote:

```
^[a-zA-Z/][a-zA-z]+$
```

But it accepts multiple slash also.

Comment: This regex wont accepts multiple slashes. Do you want to match just each line in your example or the whole of string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really basic. If you Googled for a minute or two, I'm sure you'd come up with something like

```
^[a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+$
```

The quoting of the `/` might not be necessary - depends on regex flavor.

Regards